# How do I remove the yellow border when an object has focus in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, focusrect

How do i remove the yellow border - focusRect - in as3
I've tried Stage.focusRect = false but that doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 22):

```
stage.stageFocusRect = false;
```

More info: [Rockabit blogpost](http://www.rockabit.com/2008/10/10/removing-ugly-yellow-focusrect-in-flex/)

:)

Comment: Little addition: you need to set this before you use focus. (at least it works like this at me)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem while I was making a Game. I wanted focus on my main class by typing:

```
stage.focus = this;
```

but a yellow rectangle appeared.

Then I typed:

```
stage.focus = this;
this.focusRect = false;
```

but this time, not a yellow rectangle but a yellow line appeared.

Then I typed:

```
this.focusRect = false;
stage.focus = this;
```

And this time it worked. No yellow rectangle or line appeared. So, I realized that *order does matter sometimes*.

If you're working with class just import:

```
import flash.display.Stage;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
focusRect = false;
```

In your class' constructor. Worked for me :-)

From the docs: **flash.display.InteractiveObject.focusRect(focusRect:Object):void**

Specifies whether this object displays a focus rectangle. It can take one of three values: *true*, *false*, or *null*. Values of true and false work as expected, specifying whether or not the focus rectangle appears. A value of null indicates that this object obeys the stageFocusRect property of the Stage.